# Is this termite damage? Mold damage? Something else?

Tags: mold, baseboard, damage, termite

I recently sold an old freestanding wine cellar and found a lot of dust and some mold underneath and behind it, plus this circular area on the baseboard, with some wood shavings below.  Doesn't look like the normal termite droppings I have seen in other homes.  It's jagged and uneven tiny bits of wood.  The circular shape of the damage is unique too.

I cleaned the baseboards and laminate floor with 50/50 vinegar and water after letting it sit for a bit to kill the mold spores.  Repeated that process a few days later just to be safe.  It seems likely that the mold was just living on the dust.  The flooring rep says the laminate coating should prevent any mold from actually taking root into the floor, but I did see one small nickel sized spot where the laminate was "worn away" somehow.

Thoughts?  Advice?

I now have a new wine cellar in the same location and am thinking of getting a blue led light in the wavelength that kills mold and bacteria to shine underneath it.

The HOA plans to tent our homes for termites in a couple of months.  Will Vikane also kill mold?  Just in case...

Thanks[image: circular damage to baseboard]

Comment: that looks like debris stuck to the baseboard ... is the baseboard actually damaged?

Comment: I don't see any evidence of mold or termites. The material in the picture looks like "sawdust", "crumbs" or some other "cruft" that came off of the old wine cooler or general debris that got trapped behind it--not anything associated with the baseboard or wall. I'd suggest giving it a cleaning, maybe vacuuming up the debris, and forgetting about it. Especially if you aren't seeing similar elsewhere nearby.

Comment: That looks like a knot in the wood, under the paint. Sometimes the residual resin in and around knots will make paint bubble like that, sometimes it happens immediately sometimes it happens over time.

Comment: Thanks for the input on this!  The knot idea seems like a possibility.  The paint did come off the whole circular area when I cleaned it with the 50/50 vinegar and water.   There was mold growing on the laminate floor under a curio cabinet in the same room, but again hopefully just living on the dust!